# is there a way to fix the maximum depth error in this code

Tags: python

im using this code to simulate choosing first player in a dice game
but it throws a maximum depth error from time to time
how can i fix it?
is the problem from the code or the language?

```
import random

u1 = random.randint(1, 6)
u2 = random.randint(1, 6)
u3 = random.randint(1, 6)
u4 = random.randint(1, 6)
users = [u1, u2, u3, u4]
roll_outcome = []
tie_outcome = []


def outcome():
    if len(roll_outcome) == 1:
        if roll_outcome[0] == 0:
            print("u1 is P1")
        elif roll_outcome[0] == 1:
            print("u2 is P1")
        elif roll_outcome[0] == 2:
            print("u3 is P1")
        elif roll_outcome[0] == 3:
            print("u4 is P1")
    else:
        if tie_outcome != 0:
            tie_outcome.clear()
        elif len(roll_outcome) > 1:
            for i in range(len(roll_outcome)):
                if i == 0:
                    u10 = random.randint(1, 6)
                    tie_outcome.append(u1)
                elif i == 1:
                    u20 = random.randint(1, 6)
                    tie_outcome.append(u20)
                elif i == 2:
                    u30 = random.randint(1, 6)
                    tie_outcome.append(u3)
                elif i == 3:
                    u40 = random.randint(1, 6)
                    tie_outcome.append(u4)
        roll(tie_outcome)


def roll(enterying_data):
    for i in range(len(enterying_data)):
        if max(enterying_data) == enterying_data[i]:
            roll_outcome.append(i)
    outcome()


roll(users)
```

fillings:
...........................................

Comment: You need to provide a [mre], meaning less code and the full error message with traceback.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

It's a little of both.

Your code uses recursive looping -- `roll` calls `outcome` which calls `roll` etc and this can happen an unbounded number of times.  In some languages, you'd be able to get away with this via tail-call optimization performed by the compiler or interpreter.  Python does not have this sort of optimization, so there's a limit to how deep your recursive calls can be in a Python program.

Luckily, it's not hard to make this loop iterative (which means it can loop an infinite number of times without requiring an infinitely deep stack).

```
def outcome():
    if len(roll_outcome) == 1:
        if roll_outcome[0] == 0:
            print("u1 is P1")
        elif roll_outcome[0] == 1:
            print("u2 is P1")
        elif roll_outcome[0] == 2:
            print("u3 is P1")
        elif roll_outcome[0] == 3:
            print("u4 is P1")
        return None  # done!
    else:
        if tie_outcome != 0:
            tie_outcome.clear()
        elif len(roll_outcome) > 1:
            for i in range(len(roll_outcome)):
                if i == 0:
                    u10 = random.randint(1, 6)
                    tie_outcome.append(u1)
                elif i == 1:
                    u20 = random.randint(1, 6)
                    tie_outcome.append(u20)
                elif i == 2:
                    u30 = random.randint(1, 6)
                    tie_outcome.append(u3)
                elif i == 3:
                    u40 = random.randint(1, 6)
                    tie_outcome.append(u4)
        return tie_outcome  # roll again


def roll(enterying_data):
    for i in range(len(enterying_data)):
        if max(enterying_data) == enterying_data[i]:
            roll_outcome.append(i)
    return outcome()

while users is not None:
    users = roll(users)
```

Note that you still have an issue here where the logic for settling ties doesn't really work, so the code will just go into an infinite loop at that point, but you at least won't get the `DepthError` any more...

FWIW, if the point of this code is to randomly pick P1 from among the four users, you could do this much more simply with:

```
import random

print(f"u{random.randint(1, 4)} is P1")
```